# next is not working properly in middleware using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs and i am using expressjs, Right now i am working on middleware functions,I want to know the what "next" working in middleware concept ? "next goes to next middleware" , but what is "next middleware" ? I tried with following code and whenever i hit "http://localhost:3000/" then showing "middleware 1 and middleware 2" in console, and in browser
always showing "hello world", so "next middleware" always means "router handler" (get method) ?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Middleware function 1
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Middleware 1');
  next(); // Move to the next middleware
});

// Middleware function 2
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Middleware 2');
  next(); // Move to the next middleware
});


// Route handler
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, world!');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Next is the next one you declared using `app.use`

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong. Next middleware doesn't always mean "router handler". Next() function redirect to another function.

For example in the below case,

```
// Middleware function 1
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Middleware 1");
  next(); // Move to the next middleware
});

// Route handler
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("GET /");
  next();
});

// Middleware function 2
app.use((req, res) => {
  console.log("Middleware 2");
  res.send("Hello, world!");
});
```

Output in the console:

> Middleware 1
>
> GET /
>
> Middleware 2

And response is `Hello, world!` in the browser. As a result, the next() function does not always mean a router handler.